# why print out wrong result. python enumerate, counter

Tags: python, counter, enumerate

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from collections import Counter
import itertools, collections
ListeA=['it', 'was', 'the', 'besttttttttttttttrtrtrtrtrttrtr', 'of', 'times', 'it', 'was',
        'the', 'worst', 'of', 'times', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'age', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx'
        'of', 'wisdom', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'age', 'of', 'xx'
        'foolishness']

index = collections.defaultdict(list);

for value, key in enumerate(ListeA):
    index[key].append(value)

for key1,value1 in index.items(): 
    if len(value1)>=4:  
         print value1
```

output not correct. what is problem my code. output seems

```
[0, 6, 12, 27]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
[2, 8, 14, 29]
[1, 7, 13, 28]
```

I add number to read easy `ListeA=[0'it', 1'was', 2'the',     3'besttttttttttttttrtrtrtrtrttrtr', 4'of', 5'times', 6'it', 7'was',
8'the', 9'worst', 10'of', 11'times', 12'it', 13'was', 14'the', 15'age', 16'xx', 17'xx', 18'xx', 19'xx', 20'xx', 21'xx', 22'xx', 23'xx', 24'xx', 25'xx'
26'of', 27'wisdom', 28'it', 29'was', 30'the', 31'age', 32'of', 33'xx'
34'foolishness']`

Comment: What is wrong with it? Be precise about the output you *expected*.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some commas at the end of the lines that make up your list.

Since the list items are string literals, you end up with two items next to each other with no syntax between them. A little known feature in Python is that adjacent string literals get concatenated. So `"foo" "bar"` is the same string as `"foobar"`. This can span newlines too, as long as the newline doesn't end the expression (usually because it's inside parentheses or brackets of some kind).

The issue means you'll have `"xxof"` and `"xxfoolishness"` in your data, rather than separate `"xx"` (twice), `"of"` and `"foolishness"` strings. It may also throw off your expected count.

To fix the issue, add the commas at the end of the lines where they've been missed:

```
ListeA=['it', 'was', 'the', 'besttttttttttttttrtrtrtrtrttrtr', 'of', 'times', 'it', 'was',
    'the', 'worst', 'of', 'times', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'age', 'xx', 'xx',
    'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', # add comma here
    'of', 'wisdom', 'it', 'was', 'the', 'age', 'of', 'xx', # and here
    'foolishness']
```

In addition to the commas, I also added an extra newline to break the longest line at at earlier point so that the whole thing is more likely to fit on the screen at once (with no horizontal scroll bar). [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends lines of code be no longer than 79 characters long, or 72 characters for docstrings and comments that can be rearranged in any way you want. That's only a strict requirement for code contributed to Python itself (e.g. fixes to the standard library), but many people try to follow PEP 8 in their own code, and many other Python style guides also have length limits (though they're often a bit more generous about the exact number of characters).

Answer (score 0):

The result is correct as far as I can see:

```
>>> for value, key in enumerate(ListeA): print value, key
... 
0 it
1 was
2 the
3 besttttttttttttttrtrtrtrtrttrtr
4 of
5 times
6 it
7 was
8 the
9 worst
10 of
11 times
12 it
13 was
14 the
15 age
16 xx
17 xx
18 xx
19 xx
20 xx
21 xx
22 xx
23 xx
24 xx
25 xxof
26 wisdom
27 it
28 was
29 the
30 age
31 of
32 xxfoolishness
>>>
```

Are you completely sure that the code where you "add number to read easy" is the same code as the one in the sample?

Note that if you miss a comma, Python will concatenate strings for you (see entries 25 and 32 for example).

Comment: my output is [0, 6, 12, 27]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
[2, 8, 14, 29]
[1, 7, 13, 28] every last number is wrong. it display 0,6,12 as "it" and 27 "wisdom"

Comment: I saw that. Note that this output is perfectly correct; add commas on the end of your lines of you prefer Python not concatenating strings for you.

Comment: thanks . isaw it . there is no two comma .